# mysql optimization 5 tables left joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, left-join

I currently have 5 tables:

```
trialSum
-------------
id    total
-------------
1     2000
2     1000
3     500

trialLand
-------------
id    total
-------------
1     1000
2     250
3     500

trialImp
-------------
id    total
-------------
2     250

trialBldg
-------------
id    total
-------------
1     1000
2     500

trial
---------------------
id    name     info
---------------------
1     xxxxx    xxxxx
2     xxxxx    xxxxx
3     xxxxx    xxxxx
4     xxxxx    xxxxx
```

The trial table will have the most entries into and all of the "id" fields match up with each other. Each table will have over 7000 entries in them. I am trying to create one big table that looks like:

```
    trial
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    id    name     info    totalSum    totalLand    totalImp    totalBldg
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     xxxxx    xxxxx    2000        1000         0           1000
    2     xxxxx    xxxxx    1000        250          250         500
    3     xxxxx    xxxxx    500         500          0           0
    4     xxxxx    xxxxx    0           0            0           0
```

If I do a giant MySQL query that has 4 left joins, it take over 40 minutes to complete. There has to be an easier way. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have no indexes.  If all of the `id` columns were `PRIMARY` indexes, the query should be virtually instant.  Please post your tables' structure and an `EXPLAIN` of an example long-running query.

Comment: can you give a sqlfiddle example of creating tables and insert values?

Comment: Have you tried `EXPLAIN PLAN`? You may find it helpful. More [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: I should try making all of the id columns primary keys, that would probably help a lot. I will try that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that, the left join is indeed a good way to do this. Do you have indexes on those id columns? Try adding indexes and the speed should improve. Remember to use EXPLAIN to confirm the indexes are being used appropriately. More on EXPLAIN http://www.dbtuna.com/article.asp?id=14 .

Comment: I forgot to make my id columns primary keys! Thank you that query sped up to exactly 10 sec!

Comment: Making them primary keys will automatically add a primary index to them! Glad it is solved!